Firebase verifyPhoneNumber Uncaught (in promise) Timeout
I am using firebase authentication with SMS multi-factor auth in my NextJS app. I followed the (documentation) and was able to implement it. However, after completing a successful login and after a few seconds, an error comes up

Uncaught (in promise) Timeout


Tried several solutions such as putting the functions inside a Promise and setTimeout but still getting the same error.
const verificationId = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const phoneProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider(auth);
      
      // Increase timeout and add more robust error handling
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        reject(new Error('Phone verification timeout'));
      }, 30000); // 30 seconds timeout

      phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
        formattedPhoneNumber, 
        recaptchaVerifier
      )
      .then((verificationId) => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        resolve(verificationId);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        reject(error);
      });
    });

How to possibly solve this error? Or would I just have to ignore this error?
